# How to get attribute value of XML element with saxonc.PySaxonProcessor

Tags: python

I am analyzing the use of Saxon XSLT processing in Python 3.8 with **Saxon-C-1.2.0** in Windows 10.

I can succesfully run script SaxonHEC.1.2.0.\Saxon.C.API\python-saxon**saxon_example.py**.

The last print line shows the result of getting an attribute value. I think there is an error in that code.

My question: how to get the value of an XML attribute?

```
with saxonc.PySaxonProcessor(license=False) as proc:
   # ... code left out form saxon_example.py

   xml2 = """\
<out>
  <person att1='value1' att2='value2'>text1</person>
  <person>text2</person>
  <person>text3</person>
</out>
"""
   node2 = proc.parse_xml(xml_text=xml2)
   outNode = node2.children  
   children = outNode[0].children

   attrs = children[1].attributes
   if len(attrs) == 2:
       print('node.children[1].attributes[1].string_value =', attrs[1].string_value)
       print('node.children[1].attributes[1]              =', attrs[1])
       print('node.children[1].attributes[1].__str__      =', attrs[1].__str__())
       print('node.children[1].attributes[1].__repr__     =', attrs[1].__repr__())
       print('node.children[1].attributes[1].text         =', attrs[1].text)
```

On the commandline I get:

```
node.children[1].attributes[1].string_value = att2="value2"
node.children[1].attributes[1]              = att2="value2"
node.children[1].attributes[1].__str__      = att2="value2"
node.children[1].attributes[1].__repr__     = att2="value2"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test-app.py", line 77, in <module>
    print('node.children[1].attributes[1].text         =', attrs[1].text)
AttributeError: 'saxonc.PyXdmNode' object has no attribute 'text'
```

while I expect to see only `"value2"` without the attribute name.

Comment: There is a bug issue raised against Saxon/C in relation to this problem. The fix will be in the next release and hopefully we can get a workaround to you soon: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4348

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment see link to the bug issue where we mention the fix to the bug: The `string_value` property should be calling the underlying C++ method `getStringValue`. Fix available in the next maintenance release.

Another workaround is to use the `get_attribute_value` function if you know the names of the attributes.